# Basic Haskell performance

Tags: performance, haskell, erlang

Before I start, I'd like to say that I already know that in the vast majority of use cases, performance is not some "be all end all" or isn't relevant.  I also know that "if performance is some huge concern, use FILL-IN-THE-BLANK (C, assembler, etc)."  So I don't need answers which contain what I just stated.  Assume for our purposes here that either 1) I'm just intellectually curious, or 2) I have some other relevant reason for exploring this.

At any rate, while I'm not new to functional programming (Erlang, etc) or to programming with recursion and single assignment (Prolog), I am very new to Haskell.  I was just trying to get some fundamental benchmarks on how it performs with basic tasks, like calling a function over and over again, traversing a list, etc.

To attempt to measure how well it performs just calling a function over and over again (I wanted a function which actually did nothing i.e. 'no-op,' but couldn't figure out how to make Haskell perform such a construction), I wrote this:

```
count 0 = 0
count x = 1 + count (x-1)

main = print count 100000000   -- tried various values for this integer.
```

I compared it with this Erlang program:

```
count(0) -> 0 ;
count(I) -> 1 + count(I-1)
```

To my surprise, the Erlang program ran faster over numerous runs for both programs.  In fact, it is (at least on the surface) somewhat worse than that, because even an Erlang variant program which traverses a list of x elements (vs. simply calling a function x times), runs faster than the Haskell version above.  Also, I was using a compiled version of the Haskell code (ghc --make -O3 -rtsopts) vs. the bytecode interpreter of Erlang (no Hipe).

I didn't (and still don't) know enough about Haskell to know where to start, but my first guess was to suspect laziness.  After a quick review of some online documentation I changed main to the following:

```
main = print $! count 100000000
```

It seemed to speed it up somewhat, but the Erlang versions are still faster, and in any event I'm not sure whether I did enough strictness to have enough effect, whether more could be done, whether I'm barking up the wrong tree and there is some other issue, etc.

Based on everything I've read over the years, I believe compiled Haskell should be generally faster than Erlang for most "generic tasks," although this may be less and less true the more you get into concurrency and what not.  Can anyone shed some light on these results?  "Shed light" could be rewriting my program, using different compilation flags, explaining a few things, etc.

EDIT:  I did two things, both of which had the effect of speeding up the Haskell program.  The first thing I did was add this type information to the function:

```
count :: Int -> Int
```

That put the Haskell version's performance right at the Erlang version's.  The second thing I did was remove an addition:

```
count 0 = 0
count x = count (x-1)
```

That causes the Haskell version to beat the Erlang version (for fairness I adjusted the Erlang version also); however I do wonder why the elimination of an addition would have this effect, as I don't believe Erlang is known for being some math computation beast.  I also wonder whether Haskell's compiler combined with its laziness is simply circumventing all the function calls and jumping straight to the answer.

Comment: Note that your forced strictness in `print $! ...` means nothing, since in order to be printed, something must already be evaluated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One important difference between your first version of `count` and the second version (the one which always returns 0) is that the latter is tail-recursive. A tail-recursive version of your  first function would be

```
count' :: Int -> Int
count' n = go n 0 where
    go 0 !acc = acc
    go n !acc = go (n - 1) (acc + 1)
```

which takes less than a third of the time.

The function signature matters here because without it, GHC defaults the function type to `Integer -> Integer`, which means it has to work on arbitrary-precision integers instead of `Int`s.

(It's entirely possible that GHC optimises your second version to just return a constant, but I didn't look into that. The tail-recursion by itself would make a significant performance difference, though.)

Comment: I guess I don't know what tail recursion looks like in Haskell.  The first version of the program should be tail recursive in Erlang and other languages I've worked in (Prolog, etc).  I must confess I don't understand the Haskell code you've written, thus I have more study to do.  Thanks!

Comment: I don't really understand how your first version could be tail recursive in any language. A function is tail recursive iff the last thing it does is call itself. Your version does the addition after calling itself.

Comment: Whoops - you are entirely right.  Should probably be changed to something like: count (1 + x-1)

Comment: Here you basically perform two optimizations fjh: tail recursion and bang patterns to enforce strictness over lazyness. You should explain that too in your answer.

Comment: Tail recursion without strictness isn't an optimisation.

Comment: There's no value in making things tail recursive per se. If the accumulator grows during the recursion, you still allocate lots of space. Stack vs. heap space hardly matters in Haskell, because the stack is actually allocated on the heap. Making the accumulator strict in this case ensures that it's constant space, however, so then it is an optimisation (and in a simple case such as the one of `count'`, the GHC optimizer would figure it out even without the annotation).